# Virtual IP for Azure Function Blocked by MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, asp.net-core

I've been assigned a VIP for my Timer-based Azure Function. This is fairly straight forward to find.

> Home > MyFunction > Properties

When I add this to my IP whitelist in MongoDB, my application is unable to connect. If I allow any IP access to the DB, the Azure Function connects perfectly. Likewise, when I am running the function locally via VS's emulator, my home IP address (added to Mongo's access list) works fine as well.

After spending a bit of time with support at Mongo, they inspected the firewall logs and asked me to enter a different IP address they found in the logs. When I added this IP address to the access list, the function worked. This IP was not the same as my VIP - it was not even on the /24 subnet.

My question is this. Why is the VIP on my properties screen not working? I was under the impression that is the entire point of the VIP - a static IP I can use to whitelist against my other third party services.

Has anyone else seen this and figured out a workaround?

I've included my timeout stacktrace below, but I'm 99.99% certain this is an IP access issue given the troubleshooting I've done.

```
A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/********.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/********.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
 ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server.
 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-04-30T23:52:46.2100920Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-04-30T23:52:46.2100922Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/********.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/********.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
 ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server.
 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-04-30T23:52:46.4733517Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-04-30T23:52:46.4733521Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/********.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/********.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
 ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server.
 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-04-30T23:52:46.5143705Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-04-30T23:52:46.5143708Z" }] }.
```

Comment: What is the VIP?

Comment: I've not used Azure functions but I'm guessing your VIP is an inbound IP address rather than an outbound one.

Comment: @Llama I'd agree that is what it seems, but even MongoDB's documentation indicates using the VIP should work. Here's a link to their KBA (it's referenced at the bottom): https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-integrate-azure-functions-with-mongodb